# What is the significance of the Context in Broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a `service` which I am starting on `receiving` some `broadcast receive`. So for starting the `service`, I can use:

```
ctx.startService(new Intent(ctx, myservice.class));
```

or

```
applicationContext.startService(new Intent(applicationContext, myservice.class)
```

where `ctx` is the context received in the broadcast receiver and `applicationContext` is the saved static variable that I saved in the `MainApplication`.

So what would be the difference if I use `ctx` vs `applicationContext` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Context instance, you received in onReceive(). It's completely OK to use it for purposes like starting service. And be aware of using static inctances of application context. It may lead to memory leaks, and also can become nulled in some cases.